# Microdata: including <span> as a child of <figure>

Tags: html, microdata

I'm trying to find a way of enriching information about images in a web page using schema.org.

The following code, however, doesn't seem to pass muster:

```
<figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" class="figure-container" style="width: 580px">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/media/blog-posts/gtd-apps-1.jpg" alt="The Omnifocus Mac app" width="580" height="450" title="The Omnifocus Mac app">
    <figcaption itemprop="description"><span itemprop="name">The Omnifocus Mac app window</span>, showing the Perspectives settings panel. This is a powerful feature that allows you to conceal part of the app's inherent complexity when you want to. But Things allows you to do the same more easily with its 'Areas of responsibility' feature.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Including a `<span>`element as a child of a `<figure>`element doesn't validate, but I haven't found another way of appending the `name`attribute to another tag, since the text doesn't actually require formatting.

Any suggestions as to how to achieve this would be welcome.  I'm also at a loss to understand why `<span>`can't be a child of `<figure>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the validator at http://validator.w3.org/nu/, I copy/pasted your fragment and it validated just fine.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  So does that mean a `<span>` can be a child of a `<figure>` after all?

Comment: In HTML5, if you look at the [<figcaption>](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element) element, you'll see that the content model is "Flow content" with no limitations. When you click on that, you'll see a list of tags. Since <span> is in that list, you can use it. If you look at the content model for <figure>, you'll see it expects <figcaption>.

Comment: Quod erat demonstrandum.  Thanks!